# Plot and scatter in the same axes object

Tags: python, plot, scatter

I am plotting a time series data and able to do it successfully.
However, I also want to highlight specific points on the same plot based on some condition.
In my particular example, I am coloring the data points either red or green.
This is done by me using a color map which is prepared as a list of the same length as the time series data.
I am currently doing this by using ax.plot to plot the time series data and ax.scatter to mark the specific points.
However, the axes object is not displaying anything.

Below is the code snippet:

```
`if highestCECOIbyVOL > 9:
    if close_positions_CE_key:
        markCE.append('red')
    else:
        markCE.append('green')
else:
    markCE.append('white')
     
if highestPECOIbyVOL > 9:
    if close_positions_PE_key:
        markPE.append('red')
    else:
        markPE.append('green')
else:
    markPE.append('white')
ax1.cla()
ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals_C, label = 'C', color = 'green')`enter code here`
ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals_P, label = 'P', color = 'red')
ax1.scatter(x_vals, y_vals_C, c = markCE)
ax1.scatter(x_vals, y_vals_P, c = markPE)`
```

Attached image is the plot of the time series data without scatter plot which is used to mark specific points on the plot (where the value is greater than a certain threshold). When I add scatter plot, the combined plot does not display anything and remains blank.

Comment: Which plotting library are you using? matplotlib?

Comment: yes matplotlib.

Comment: Could you add some sample data that is similar to what you are working with and if possible some rough drawing of what you want. An image of your current output would also be helpful. Not really clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: After some testing, it could be an issue with using axes. Using plt.scatter and plt.plot in combination works fine.

Comment: That is what I am unable to figure out. I have made a sample program with the same issue being replicated. Can't share the complete original code. Will post a new question with the sample code along with the data. thanks for your help.